# Run VMware inside nested VM hosted by Hyper-V

Tags: virtualization

I have Hyper-V running on my system and I thought I would host a VM on my system to expose a second Windows 8.1 VM on top of the system with Hyper-V. My goal is to run VMware inside this virtual machine and noticing that Hyper-V is not installed on the guest VM I still could not install VMware. I then noticed services inside the guest saying that relate to HyperV so I disabled them. Still could not install VMware. So I ran the guest VM with HyperV No Boot option and still could not install VMware.

What's the reason for this if the virtual machine guest has no sign that HyperV is installed yet VMware installer says it is? Is there a flag I can set to override this?

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve here?

Answer (score 4):

You *cannot* run a VM inside a VM because the virtualization features of your CPU will not be exposed to the first level guests. VMWare knows if a guest is on Hyper-V and (rightly) prevents installation.

Comment: ESXi can run within an ESXi instance, though it's not supported. Hyper-V does not pass the virtualization capabilities of the host CPU to guests, so you can't nest anything inside it.

Comment: True. ESXi lets you use "software virtualization" for chips without the hardware virtualization support, but like you said...not supported and should never be done.

Comment: Recent Hyper-V does support [nested virtualization](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/hyper-v-on-windows/user-guide/nested-virtualization). Here is a [detailed article](https://dscottraynsford.wordpress.com/2016/04/22/install-a-vmware-esxi-6-0-hypervisor-in-a-hyper-v-vm/) on how to enable it via [Enable-NestedVm.ps1](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/Virtualization-Documentation/blob/master/hyperv-tools/Nested/Enable-NestedVm.ps1) script.

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't prevent _installation_, the message isn't displayed until power-on.